# I can't update the state from Redux with Redux Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I am trying to learn how to use useDispatch and useSelector, but I don't really know what I am doing wrong. The problem is that instead of replacing my state with the new one, it deletes it.

index.jsx

```
const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

actionCreators.js

export const fetchGitHubTrendingTopics = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch('https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=javascript', {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json'
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_GITHUB_TOPICS',
          payload: json.items.slice(0, 5)
        });
      })
      .catch(err => err.message);
  };
};

actionTypes.js

export const FETCH_GITHUB_TOPICS = 'FETCH_GITHUB_TOPICS';

rootReducer.js

export const initialState = {
  topics: [],
  repos: [],
  battleRepos: []
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, { type, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    case FETCH_GITHUB_TOPICS:
      return { ...state, topics: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

INITIAL: [image]
AFTER PRESSING THE BUTTON: [image]

if I do it the old way, it updates it and it works. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you have in your reducer ?

Comment: I will update the question shortly.

Comment: can you console.log or show the real error!!!

Comment: I updated the post with the problem.

Comment: You are asking how to use `useDispatch` and `useSelector` correctly and you didn't add code where you are using them. Please add code of your component when you are dispatching your `fetchGitHubTrendingTopics` action. And did you already check that payload in reducer is not `undefined`?